# Apportable app icon

Tags: apportable

Since the latest versions of Apportable the app icon of my app appears too small in the Android launcher (half the size of other apps' icons).

I tried to set the "ICON" property in `configuration.json` file but could not make it work.

```
"ICON": "./Icon.png",
```

What is the reference folder here?

I have the usual `Icon-*.png` files in the `/Resources` folder of my Obj-C code (the largest one being `Icon-72@2x.png`). Can I directly point to one of them ? Or do I need to copy the desired icon into the `.approj` folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally it seems that the reference folder is the "root" of the project, i.e the folder containing the .approj folder.

So in my case the following worked just fine:

```
"ICON": "./<app>/Resources/Icon-72@2x.png",
```

Answer (score 2):

File references in the `configuration.json` are relative to the folder that includes the `.xcodeproj` file.

Comment: Well in fact it seems that the reference folder is the one containing the <app>.approj folder (in my case the folder containing .xcodeproj is a subfolder of this one)